# I want to print selected start row and end row from table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to print selected start row and end row using javascript . But my code works start row and end row but if show print preview screen can`t show correctly.It is printing all.How can I do that?

var work = $("#rom-table-id").find("tr");

```
                    for (var i = change_color_start; i <= change_color_end; i++) {
                        $(work[i]).addClass('print-selected-row');


                        console.log(work[i]);

                    }   

                    if (change_color_end) {
                        // 印刷プレビュー用別ウィンドウOpen
                        window.open('', 'new_window', 'fullscreen=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');

                        // SochiKubun:TD orATC or ALL、SelectedStartKoban:選択開始行の項番、SelectedEndKoban：選択終了行の項番
                        var form = document.createElement('form');
                        var printRomVerAction = location.pathname.substring(0, location.pathname.toUpperCase().lastIndexOf("WSM24G01") + 8) + '/PrintRomVer';
                        form.setAttribute('action', printRomVerAction);
                        form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
                        form.setAttribute('target', 'new_window');
                        form.setAttribute('id', 'SochiButton');
                        form.style.display = 'none';
                        document.body.appendChild(form);
                        var input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                        input.setAttribute('name', 'SochiKubun');
                        var sochi = $('.sochi-kind').text();
                        input.setAttribute('value', sochi);
                        form.appendChild(input);

                        input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                        input.setAttribute('name', 'SelectedStartKoban');
                        var koban = $(work[i - 1]).children('td:first').text();
                        console.log("koban is " , koban)
                        input.setAttribute('value', koban);
                        console.log("after insert value ,start row of result is ", koban);
                        form.appendChild(input);

                        input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                        input.setAttribute('name', 'SelectedEndKoban');
                        var koban = $(work[selected_end_row]).children('td:first').text();
                        input.setAttribute('value', koban);
                        console.log("after insert value ,end row of result is ", koban);
                        form.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: You can use http://printjs.crabbly.com/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to

**1. filter the data on the server**

or

**2. place the data you want to print into a PDF file and send the PDF file to the 
printer.**

The problem you are experiencing is due to the fact that `^P` or `[File][Print]` fetches the page from the server (or browser cache). So the modifications to the data on the previous loaded page are lost and don't print.

If this must be done from the client (browser), then the PDF solution is the answer.